# Patching the lawn by adding seeds and then soil over the bald patches - when?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

When is the best time to put seeds in your lawn to fill in the bald patches? Now (November) or in spring (March-April)?

Comment: I don't remember where you live.  November is late for seeding unless you are in zone 5 and up.  Otherwise, seeding in late September early October with at least 4 weeks growth before winter is best.  That would include at least 2 mowings, one light fertilizing low nitrogen to prepare for winter.  Whether or not you are seeding patches or entire lawns I don't think you have enough time for germination and establishing roots.  Again, it depends on where you live...I am assuming cool season grasses?  Wait till spring...